# A way to retrieve some data from a table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrieve some data in a table with certain criteria.

With the following criteria:

1. JurPengampu = 17
2. NRP codes must be different from one another, if the same, then the IdJurus = 17 is taken

The explanation is in the picture.
[image]

Thank you for help,,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTWgn.png)

Comment: Please, no images. Show us sample table data and the expected result as formatted text instead,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use analytical function as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by kodenrp order by idjurusan) as rn
  from your_table t) t
where rn = 1
```

Or use `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
select t.*
  from your_table t
 where not exists 
       (select 1 from your_Table tt
         where t.kodenrp = tt.kodenrp and tt.idjurusan < t.idjhurusan)
```

Comment: @AdityaSIM . . . These are both quite simple.  Your comment doesn't make sense.